# Swift - check if attributed text is empty

Tags: swift, string, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a UITextField on which I set a current value as attributed text as follows:

```
public var currentValue: NSAttributedString {
    get {
        return inputField.attributedText ?? NSAttributedString()
    }
    set {
        inputField.attributedText = newValue
    }
}
```

This was previously just a String but I now need to add formatting to parts of the text.

However, I have a method I need to pass on these fields which begins with the condition to see if the field is empty. Previously I started this with:

```
if textField.currentValue.isEmpty {
  // Perform logic
}
```

However, obviously NSAttributedText has no isEmpty member. How can I perform the same check on NSAttributedText?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NSAttributedText` has no `isEmpty` property but it has one called [`length`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1418432-length). You can simply check if it is equal to zero:

```
if currentValue.length == .zero {
  // Perform logic
}
```

Another option is to simply check if your text field `hasText`

```
if textField.hasText {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's also `attributedText.string.isEmpty`